# Example of a higher degree Polynomial without a "paired" imaginary root?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

In quadratics, imaginary roots come in pairs, ostensibly due to the quadratic formula's +/- before the $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$   (aka: Complex conjugate root theorem)

In higher degree polynomials, can you ever have an "unpaired" imaginary root?
If yes, an example to work through?

Comment: If you have a polynomial with real coefficients, complex roots will appear in conjugate pairs.  However, there are polynomials with complex coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For polynomials of any degree with real coefficients, all complex roots are paired by the theorem you gave.  If complex coefficients are allowed, we have the simple example:

$$x-i=0$$

Comment: Where is the complex coefficient?  The x has a coeff of 1.   Are you referring to the "+c", so to speak?  Instead of a constant, it's an imaginary?      The  roots of the equation above is simply i, and not -i, right ?

Comment: @JackOfAll yes, the last constant can usually be referred to as the $x^0$ coefficient.

Comment: Oh, right.   $0x^0$  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Condition for paired roots is that the coefficients of the polynomial are real. So an example of unpaired complex root would be some polynomial with complex coefficients

Comment: Can you write an example?  I've never seen an equation like this.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have a polynomial of degree $n$ of real coefficients,

$$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_nx^n$$

Suppose $z$ is a root, that is

$$\sum_{i=0}^na_nz^n=0$$

Take the conjugate function on both sides,

$$\sum_{i=0}^na_n\bar{z}^n=0$$

Hence the conjugate is also a root. Hence imaginary root come in pairs.